How to change color variable in bootsrap
So I've been trying to change the primary/secondary, etc.. colors in my project, but it's not working.
Here is my code: https://github.com/AndreSantosRaposo/UniShare/tree/main/front-end/src
custom.scss is inside components.
I trying replacing the color value in the variable.scss like $primary: black !default``but nothing changed. Now I tried to create a custom.scss but nothing changes either. What am I doing wrong?

Why would you want to change the default colors when you can easily define your own color classes in CSS?

Are you changing the variable directly inside the Bootstrap's source code? It's not recommended to change something inside the variable.scss source code.
What you want to do instead is, create another scss file that imports the Bootstrap source code, and then overrides the variables there.
For example, We'll build a custom.scss file.
// Include functions first (so you can manipulate colors, SVGs, calc, etc)
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";

// Include any default variable overrides here
$primary: #2789d8;
$secondary: #262626;

@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

Then, you need to compile the custom.scss into a css file. Do it with a sass library. Install it globally using npm.
npm install -g sass

Then just run the command to build or watch the scss file.
sass --watch custom.scss custom.css --style compressed

You would want to specify the directory where the files exist.
Finally, you can use the customized Bootstrap inside the custom.css file. You can call it on the root app.

Remember to call the .css file, not the .scss file except your app is compatible with auto-compiling a sass format.


Instead of changing the default colors on bootstrap, you can define your own colors in CSS:
.primary-custom {
color: black !important;
}

Then you add primary-custom to your class:
<p class="primary-custom">My custom primary color is black.</p>

